# JavaScript Add function called as many times as you wanted

Tags: javascript

The simplest question for that is like to write a function that could return the sum of all the parameters. How I can do that?

```
function add () {

}
add(1)(2)(3)();  //6
add(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)()  //35
```

Comment: Where is your effort?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function)

Comment: Please attempt to write this function.  I would suggest changing "Unlimited parameters" to an array based on what may be your skill level.

Comment: That's not a function returning the sum of "all the parameters", there's a single parameter, and you're calling `add` once, and calling some other function afterwards.

Comment: @matmo No, this is not a function taking multiple parameters.

Comment: A function that returns the sum of all the paramaters would be called like `add(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286900/identify-how-the-function-has-been-called-in-closure-javascript/47287290#47287290

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you need:

```js
function add(value) {
   return (val) => val !== undefined ? add(value + val) : value;
}

console.log(add(2)(2)()); //4
console.log(add(2)(2)(5)(5)()); //14
console.log(add(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)()); //5
console.log(add(1)(1)(0)(1)(1)()); //4
```

---

**How it works**

For every call it declares a function inside, in result it creates a closure(persistent scope) in every call. Function created in that way has access to its parameter + previous call parameter due to existing closure.

So if I call add(2)(3)():

- add(2) - returns function with visible 2 value
- add(2)(3) - calls second function with input 2 + 3 and return third function with visible value equal 5
- add(2)(3)() - ends computation due to empty param and returns the value

To finish the computation pipe the last call needs to be without a value.

Comment: @KonradD I did, works fine if used as in OP's question.

Comment: Testes and work as a charm :). Wait I will add a snippet

Comment: @MaciejSikora - nice answer (UVed), but `val ?` will also return a result if `val` is 0.

Comment: @KonradD Because the function returns a function. The last call w/o a parameter fails the ternary expression so doesn't continue to `add`.

Comment: @KonradD I fixed the 0 problem + added some description

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is to create a closure with a variable `sum` that we can update, and return the `sum` if the value is undefined, or the the inner function:

```js
const add = (n) => {
  let sum;
  
  const inner = (n) => n === undefined ? sum : (sum = (sum || 0) + n, inner);
  
  return inner(n);
};

console.log(add(1)(2)(3)());  //6
console.log(add(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)());  //35
```

Comment: IMO questions like this are best left as an exercise for the asker, potentially providing hints to how to go about solving them. Teach a man to fish and all that.

Comment: @DaveNewton - I know, but I'm not really concerned about the OP. Just wanted to see other answers.

Comment: AFAICT that doesn't require posting an answer, but ok.

Comment: @DaveNewton it is not true that such approach is fully wrong. It is close to currying and enables to use functions with encapsulated values over the application instead of variables. You thread function as first class citizen instead of variable with pure value.

Comment: @MaciejSikora I don't think it's wrong at all, I'm just opposed to answering questions that don't show any effort. The point of questions like the OP was asked is either to (a) gauge knowledge, or (b) make them think. Handing over answers defeats the purpose on both counts. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) like this:

```js
function add(...values) {
  return values.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0)
}

console.log(add(1, 4, 34, 45, 3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: Solves a different problem.

Comment: Observe the OP's question: `add(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)()` which is not a function taking multiple parameters, rather a function returning a function.

Comment: `¯\(°_o)/¯` It's not an uncommon interview question or classroom exercise; it shows a basic understanding of non-trivial JS.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn instead of forEach you should use reduce and no need to have this sum variable at all.